# What are the required permissions for Get-AzureADServicePrincipal?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to run a PowerShell script for assigning appRoles from a DevOps service principal.

The DevOps service principal has the following permissions assigned and admin consented:

- Application.Read.All
- AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All
- User.Read

It fails on the step where it gets the service principal which is the owner of the roles to assign:

```
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -filter "displayName eq '$AppName'"
```

with the error message:

```
Error occurred while executing GetServicePrincipals 
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
RequestId: a8fadf67-94d6-40ec-ad88-6562cf9f6d80
DateTimeStamp: Tue, 23 Jun 2020 16:51:36 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

I expected Application.Read.All to grant this permission, since the resource I am searching for is an Application.

What permission do I need to run this line of script, and where is this documented? I am applying the principle of least-privilege and don't want to give the Devops sp an administrative role. I only want to apply the specific permission required to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you assigned a permission `User.Read` which only exists in Delegated permissions. So I guess the other 2 permissions `Application.Read.All` and `AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All` you configured are also Delegated permissions.

But now you are run `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` from a service principal, that means it needs Application permissions (no user here).

And when I track this cmd via Fiddler4, the backend request is `GET https://graph.windows.net/exxxxx4e-bd27-40d5-8459-23xxxxa757fb/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.6&%24filter=displayName%20eq%20%27xxxx%27`

`graph.windows.net` is for Azure AD Graph and `graph.microsoft.com` is for Microsoft Graph.

So it is calling Azure AD Graph instead of Microsoft Graph. What you need are Application permissions of Azure AD Graph.

Based on my test, `Application.ReadWrite.All` and `Directory.Read.All` can meet your needs. If you don't want the service principal to have the write permission, you can choose `Directory.Read.All`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This made me realise that the AzureAD module is fundamentally unsuited to our needs, since Azure AD Graph permissions are too broad. We can use Microsoft Graph permissions if we rewrite our scripts to call the MS Graph API, and I've proved that this works today. The gap in my understanding was the difference between AD Graph and MS Graph.